# Java: Get the second highest ancestor of a descendant treenode

Tags: java, treemodel

Using the `DefaultTreeModel`, `defaultmutbletreenode`'s `getRoot()` returns it's highest ancestor, but how would you go one generation down to return it's second highest ancestor?

```
root
 - ancestor 1
  - some parent
   - some child
 - ancestor 2
  - some parent
   - another parent
    - some child
```

so how to find `ancestor 1`, given `some child` in this branch, the depth of each branch differs for each `ancestor` node under `root`.

I nee to traverse up to `ancestor 1` from `some child`, and also for a deeper branch, given `some child`, it will find `ancestor 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TreeNode[] nodeArray = tree.getPathToRoot(nodeInQuestion);
TreeNode secondFromRoot;

if ((nodeArray != null) && // I'm not sure this can actually happen.
    (nodeArray.length > 1)) // current node is not the root node.
{
   secondFromRoot = nodeArray[1];
}
else
{
   ... decide what makes sense here.
}
```